# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE with multiple values with space between them

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 100+ list of names provided to me in a excel that I need to map to my internal system and extract their current status. As such what is the most efficient way to do that SQL in Oracle

**Sample names like**

```
Peter Silver & Partners
Patric+Kennedy
WBTA/Worldwide
Equivalence
Mart Gang
Cornard Scofi + Treno
```

**Is this the best way**

```
regexp_like (upper(INTERNAL_NAME ,'PETER SILVER & PARTNERS$|PATRIC+KENNEDY$|WBTA/WORLDWIDE$|EQUIVALENCE$|MART GANG$|CORNARD SCOFI + TRENO$'))
```

HOW DO WE HANDLE SPACES B/W STIRNGS with REGEXP_LIKE

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or something that will be scheduled and run regularly? Are you connecting Excel to Oracle via ODBC?

Comment: OK, we know what you have in your excel.  We do _not_ know what you are dealing with in the oracle db.   Exactly what are you matching those names to?  Exactly what constitutes a "match", and what do you do with the matched data?

Comment: one time thing.. no not connecting excel via ODBC. So the name in excel is similar name in our system, if it marches then we pick corresponding details