# Pandas merge different excel sheets into one along with a new column derived by sheet name

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge different excel sheets into one and also add a new column as a corresponding sheet name

The below code merge all sheets, but how do I add a sheet name as a column ??

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\xx\\FC_List.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
print(single_df)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Users\\FC_List.csv", index=False)
```

below code fetch sheet name

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\cc\\FC_List.xlsx", None);
df.keys()
```

can u advise how to add both together as a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into steps.

```
 import pandas as pd
 dfs = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\xx\\FC_List.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
 df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=dfs.keys())
```

This will set your index as the column name, you can then reset it and rename it.

you could also do something like.

```
df = pd.concat([sheet.assign(src_sheet=sheet_name) for sheet_name,sheet in dfs.items()])
```

Comment: Thank you. I get errors AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'assign'---dfs = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\CC\\FC_Full_List.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
#df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=dfs.keys())
df = pd.concat([sheet.assign(src_sheet=sheet_name) for sheet,sheet_name in dfs.items()])
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\raleti\\FC_CC_List.csv", index=False)

Comment: @stackuser apoloigies, I didnt test as I wasn't on a machine w/excel, see edit.

Comment: so this works df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=dfs.keys()) but doesn't do df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\CC\\FC_List.csv", index=False).. any idea why this is not writing to CSV with that concatenated column

Comment: Revised worked. THANKS. Also, as a follow-up is there a quick pattern matching the output names to a oracle table internally.. i got the oracle connection set.. how do i pattern match this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821373/oracle-sql-name-to-entity-mapping?noredirect=1#comment118120047_66821373